# Small StackExchange logo on top of StackExchange sites' pages not clickable in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange

In Internet Explorer 7, the first time I visit a [Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) I've never logged into, the small StackExchange logo at the top of the page is a clickable link. But if I refresh the page, only the bottom row or two of pixels of the Stack Exchange logo is a clickable link. The rest of the logo results in an arrow mouse pointer and does nothing when you click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution for this problem: In the style sheet all.css, in the item #notify-container, add `height: 0;` .

Currently, in the style sheet all.css, #notify-container has a width of 100% but no height specified. For this element, when the width is specified but not the height, Internet Explorer 7 seems to set the height to about one line of text. This causes the notify-container div to cover most of the StackExchange logo and prevent all but the bottom row or two of pixles from being a clickable link. (The notify-container div also seems to cover the other links on the top right of the page, but they remain clickable, I'm not sure why.)

The first time the page is visited, javascript fills the notify-container div with the welcome message and shifts the rest of the page down. When the "x" is clicked the notify-container div is removed or hidden. So on the first page visit, the notify-container div never covers the StackExchange logo.

Comment: Bavi_H thanks for the solution! (it works). We're pushing the fix very soon.

Comment: @jin fix confirmed. Thanks Bavi! upvoted :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing it so quickly. (Once the time-limit expires, I guess I'll accept my answer.)